# How come this function doesn't return 0?

Tags: c, recursion

I am studying C and recursive functions and I wrote a recursive function to find out if a given string is a palindrome.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int testPalindrome(char str[], size_t, size_t);

int main() {
    int x;
    char string[6] = "rpdar";       // palindrome "radar" for test
    x = testPalindrome(string, 4, 0);
    printf("Palindrome: %d\n", x);  
}

int testPalindrome(char str[], size_t sizeMax, size_t sizeMin) {
    if (sizeMax > sizeMin) {
        if (str[sizeMax] != str[sizeMin]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return testPalindrome(str, sizeMax - 1, sizeMin + 1); // the function compares the first letter with the last, the second with the penultimate and so on
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}
```

The program prints `1` if it is, otherwise `0`.
It works, but I would like to know how come `testPalindome` doesn't return 0 if I don't write `return` before the recursive call:

```
int testPalindrome(char str[], size_t sizeMax, size_t sizeMin) {
    if (sizeMax > sizeMin) {
        if (str[sizeMax] != str[sizeMin]) { 
            return 0;
        } else {
            testPalindrome(str, sizeMax - 1, sizeMin + 1); 
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I think my inability to understand the problem lies in how a recursive call works.

The way I see it, in the latter case, at one point, `testPalindrome` assumes the value `0`, but since there is no `return` before the call, it must complete any other instructions
left in the function and therefore eventually assumes value `1`.
Does that make sense?

Comment: If you don't return the result of the function call the code proceeds and returns 1 unconditionally at the bottom. Since you don't use the return value you could just delete the recursive call and there would be no change. Your function becomes a check for only the first and last character of the string. If they match you get 1, if not you get 0.

Answer (score 0):

You will get 0 **if your first and last character are not the same and if your str length is > 1**, otherwise it will return 1.

Try your function with :

- "aba" would return (1)
- "abc" would return (0)
- "abca" would return (1) : this is your code problem

Your function work but **not for all the possibilities**.

It's important to test your code with differents tests that you had made.